# sql select command , from date to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a grid with some data and 2 cells of its date range (grid start date --> grid end date)

A user got an option to enter a date range (also  user start date and  user end date) and my goal is to show the grid to the user  with  the rows that any of his typed dates included in the  date range of the grid  (grid start date --> grid end date)  any of the typed dates (user start date or   user end date).

for example a row in the grid can be

```
sport-football games-23/11/2014-27/12/2014
```

and the user typed `14/10/14 - 25/12/14`, this will show the grid row because `25/12/14` is included in its date range.

p.s

i also need to confirm the companyId since i only want to show the users company

```
 WHERE (companyID = @companyId) 
 AND ((DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, dateStart, @tmp1) >= 0 
 AND DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, dateEnd, @tmp1) <= 0) 
 OR (DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, dateStart, @tmp2) >= 0) 
 AND DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, dateEnd, @tmp2) <= 0))
```

tmp1 and tmp2 are the user start and end date
 for some reason some of the "("  seem to automatically removed on excute so maybe it ruins it?

Comment: visual studio with microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from your_table t 
where (@d1 > t.LowDate and @d1 <= t.HighDate) 
or (@d2 > t.LowDate and @d2 <= t.HighDate)
```

Won't it work for you?